# How to convert an epoch milliseconds timestamp in UInt64 to DispatchTime?

Tags: ios, swift

We have an epoch timestamp in `UInt64` as input.

May I know, how can we convert it to `DispatchTime`

```
let timestampInMilliseconds: UInt64 = ...

// How we can convert timestampInMilliseconds to DispatchTime?
let dispatchTime: DispatchTime = ...

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: dispatchTime) {
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First find out how many milliseconds is that time stamp since now:

```
let secondsSinceNow = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(timestampInMilliseconds)).timeIntervalSinceNow
let millisSinceNow = Int(secondsSinceNow * 1000)
```

Then you can get your dispatch time by adding to `.now()`:

```
let dispatchTime: DispatchTime = .now() + .milliseconds(millisSinceNow)
```

Comment: Isn't this kind of round-about? `timeIntervalSinceNow` is equivalent to subtracting "now", but later you add it back in with `.now() + ...`. Are the two "now"s different in some way?

Comment: @Alexander I admit it is. Feel free to post an answer if you have a better way :)

Comment: @Alexander I _think_ the two "nows" are different in that, the first `Date` "now" is the number of milliseconds since 1970, but the dispatch time "now" is the number of nanoseconds since boot.

Comment: Ah, that's subtle, but makes sense. One improvement I can suggest: you can skip the manual s -> ms conversion by just using [`DIspatchTimeInterval.seconds(secondsSinceNow)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchtimeinterval)

Comment: @Alexander But `secondsSinceNow` is a `Double` (aka `TimeInterval`). `DispatchTimeInterval.seconds` accepts an `Int`. Directly converting the number of seconds to `Int` might lose some precision that was in the original timestamp, which was in milliseconds, right?

Comment: You're right, yet again! Yeah, this seems to be the minimal correct code for the case!